# Duda para crear un ModelFactory Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel

Sabiendo que tengo 3 tablas:

personas (id, nombre, apellido)

```
$factory->define(SIMante\Personas::class, function ($faker) {
    return [
        'nombres' => $faker->firstName,
        'apellidos' => $faker->lastName,
    ];
});
```

perfiles (id, nombre)

```
$factory->define(SIMante\Perfiles::class, function ($faker) {
    return [
        'nombre' => $faker->unique()->randomElement($array = array ('Administrador','Usuario','Operario')),
    ];
});
```

users (id, id_personas (unique), nombre, correo, clave, id_perfiles)

No entiendo como crear el factory para la tabla  puesto que la columna id_personas debe ser unica para cada usuario.

aca lo que llevo:

```
$factory->define(SIMante\User::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'id_personas' => $faker->unique()->randomElement(SIMante\Perfiles::all()->id),
        'nombre' => $faker->unique()->userName,
        'correo' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'clave' => bcrypt('123456'),
        'id_perfiles' => SIMante\Perfiles::all()->random()->id,
    ];
});
```

pero eso me arroja el siguiente error

> undefined property: illuminate\database\eloquent\collection::$id

He intentado de varias maneras, pero todas me dan error, aunque esa es la que mas veo lógica de usar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías intentar con el método pluck para obtener solo el valor del id, como lo estás haciendo no es posible, pues tienes una colección (que es una especie de array) y estás llamando una propiedad en el arreglo, la cual no existe.

```
'id_personas' => $faker->unique()->randomElement(SIMante\Personas::all()->pluck('id')->toArray())
```

Comment: Con ese metodo me arroja el siguiente error:

[OverflowException] Maximum retries of 10000 reached without finding a unique value

Comment: Agrega el método `toArray()`, mira la edición.

Comment: no había visto tu comentario pero si leí la modificación, edite el comentario mio al nuevo error.

Comment: Vas a tener que hacer un dump de esa línea a ver que información estás obteniendo, a ver si corresponde a lo que esperas. Por cierto, no debería ser `SIMante\Personas` en vez de `SIMante\Perfiles` ?

Comment: Entre tantas modificaciones me debi haber confundido, disculpa, estas en lo correcto, es "SIMante\Personas". Aunque tu sugerencia me solvento el problema porque no habia hecho eso (del pluck). Gracias.